# Make two elements with dimensions inline

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make the two elements in the header, the pink section and the green section, be inline ( in one line and not wrapping to a new line as the green section is currently).

However, I can't use display:inline; as the items need to have a width.

How can I achieve both of these elements being inline and keep their widths?

Here is the page where the elements are: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/270523/help/new.html

Comment: You probably need to either use display:inline-block; or float:left; - if you use floats, remember to clear them :)

Comment: @daniel I believe I am using inline-block. That is why I am confused why it is dropping to a new line. Block-level should do that not inline-block.

Comment: you can do it with inline-block, 20% and 80%, but if you choose this option, you have to delete the whitespaces in the html (and possibly use #logo,#input{vertical-align:top;})

Comment: why 20, 80? why not 25, 75?

Comment: you can do that as well :) just remember to delete the whitespaces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inline-block solution:

```
#logo {
    width: [WIDTH1]%;
    min-width: 225px;
    background: pink;
}

#input{   
    width: [WIDTH2]%;
    background: green;
}

#input,#logo {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

Where [WIDTH1] + [WIDTH2] = 100%.
For this to work, you need to delete the whitespaces between the two elements.

So not like now:

```
<section id="logo"></section>
<section id="input">
    <input id="searchInput" type="text" name="search" autocomplete="off">
</section>
```

But instead:

```
<section id="logo"></section><section id="input">
    <input id="searchInput" type="text" name="search" autocomplete="off">
</section>
```

Comment: I tried this solution and it is not working. The current file has this solution implmented. Here is another link: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/270523/help/new.html
Also, I don't get what the difference is between the HTML markup in the two versions you have above. One has a carriage-return / new line after #logo.

Comment: I got it to work, but only with a 20% and 80% ratio. No other combination of numbers even if they add up to 100 is working...

Comment: The difference in my two versions is that there is no whitespace. Inline-block treats whitespace kinda like a character, like: " ". (In fact I'm pretty sure the space reflected is actually determined by the elements font-size) -- so you need to remove the whitespace / carriage-returns / newline.

Answer (score 0):

Your section input is dropping because it is having extra width, make it around 77% then it will work for you.

```
#input{width:77%;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You've set the float to the #input section but not the #logo section.

```
#logo {
width:20%;
float: left;
}
```

Comment: Is there a way I can achieve this without floats? On anything? Because don't I have to use clear / a clearfix hack then?

Comment: weirdly enough, I got it to work, but only when the pink section is 20% and the green section is 80%.

Answer (score 0):

first of all it is really nice You use html5 tags its good for You. In my opinion the easiest way is use a float for all of elements in header, but remember to `clear:both` parent tag.

Here is demo of modified your code: http://jsfiddle.net/bartekbielawa/WgtAP/

Comment: I love HTML5, i've been using it since the summer of 2010!

Comment: In your jsFiddle, the green section is still dropping to a new line.